# how change the default generated test class in IDEA？

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using idea to generate test class after clicking right mouse button by using JUnit ，However the test class will be in /src fold，But I want this test class will be in  out of /src to keep my project clear，How can i deal question to change the default generated test class location...

Comment: You might try out a **maven** project with src/main/java/ and src/test/java/.

Comment: Do you have any folders marked as "test source directory"? How did you create your project? Purely in IDEA or using something like Maven/Gradle?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, go to File --> Project Structure --> Project --> Compiler output, there select the appropriate folder/directory to have the generated test classes. Also, you can ignore those generated test classes in .gitignore if you don't want to commit to a remote repository.